# I cannot change RailsInstaller command prompt buffer size

Tags: windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.1, command-prompt

I'm using Windows7, and I installed Ruby on Rails with RailsInstaller. This comes with "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails", which I think is just a regular cmd prompt that automatically starts Rails...

Anyway, the problem I'm having is that I cannot change the buffer size. I have changed the buffer size to 999 in the Options tab of the Properties, but to no avail.

I've done the same thing to the regular command prompt that comes with Windows and it worked.

Comment: This may sound confusing but, which Properties->Options tab are you using? When I did it via the C:\ icon in the upper left of the window it is persistent and changes it for subsequent command prompts. Also what version of Ruby?

Comment: I have ruby1.9.2 and rails3.1.1. I have tried using Properties tab from right-clicking the window icon like you suggested and the desktop shortcut I created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem. I could get the buffer size working correctly in the regular Windows command prompt, so I just made another shortcut to that, and then in the Properties->Shortcut tab I changed Target to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /E:ON /K C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\setup_environment.bat C:\RailsInstaller`

Still not sure why changing Options on the cmd prompt that came with railsinstaller didn't work though...